# How to validate if an element of an array is an array itself?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-validator

Given this input:

```
[
    'key' => 'value',
]
```

How to validate to ensure that:

1. `key` attribute exists
2. Its value is an array (with any number of elements)

I expected this constraint to work

```
    $constraint = new Collection([
        'key' => new Required([
            new Type('array'),
            new Collection([
                'value' => new Required([
                    new NotBlank(),
                ]),
            ]),
        ]),
    ]);
```

but it throws an exception:

```
Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException: Expected argument  of type "array or Traversable and ArrayAccess", "string" given
```

What am I missing?

PS: it's symfony v2.7.1

PPS: just to clarify: I know one can use a callback. If I wanted to re-implement the validation manually from scratch - I wouldn't have used symfony at the very first place. So the question is particularly about **combining** the existing constraints and not about using a callback constraint..

Comment: something like `if ((is_array($a)) or ($a instanceof Traversable))`

Comment: @Umair the question is particularly about using symfony2 validator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the **exact same problem** two nights ago.

The conclusion at the very end was that `Symfony2` validation has no "fast-fail" validation. That is, even if your `Type()` constraint would fail it would proceed with other constraints and thus fail with `UnexpectedTypeException` exception.

However, I was able to find a way to tackle that:

```
$constraint = new Collection([
    'key' => new Required([
        new Type(['type' => 'array']),
        new Collection([
            // Need to wrap fields into this
            // in order to provide "groups"
            'fields' => [ 
                'value' => new Required([
                    new NotBlank(),
                ]),
            ],
            'groups' => 'phase2' // <-- THIS IS CRITICAL
        ]),
    ]),
]);

// In your controller, service, etc...
$V = $this->get('validator');

// Checks everything by `Collection` marked with special group
$violations = $V->validate($data, $constraint);

if ( $violations->count()){
    // Do something
}

// Checks *only* "phase2" group constraints
$violations = $V->validate($data, $constraint, 'phase2');

if ( $violations->count()){
    // Do something
}
```

Hope that this helps a bit. Personally, I find it annoying that we need to do this. Some sort of "fast-fail" flag within `validator` service would be much helpful.

Comment: That is finally something that looks like an answer, thanks :-) 3 days left for bounty to expire, this one is the only candidate yet.

Answer (score 2):

You're saying the `Collection` constraint should just fail instead of throwing an exception because `'value'` is a `string` and not an `array`.

There is a recently logged Symfony bug for this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14943

Comment: Constraints have a concept of so called "default options", which is `type` in case of a `Type` constraint. Which means that `new Type(['type' => 'array'])` is identical to `new Type('array')`. See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/Type.php#L32 and https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraint.php#L144

Comment: Doing type validation is always "fun" because at what level the actual type error occurred is rarely clear.  Sorry about that, try this new answer.

Comment: "Your input has the string 'value' as the value of index 'key', which is not an array, so the exception is thrown here" --- I know why it was thrown. The question was: how to write a constraint that would accept **ANY INPUT**. If I could guarantee that input is always valid - I wouldn't use validators. "If you change your input to" --- would you literally put it on your site: please dear hackers, don't pass us what we not except since it crashes our application?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Callback` constraint([docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html)) where you can implement your custom validation logic.

The other way is to create custom constraint and validator classes. ([docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html))

Comment: What exactly are you suggesting? To reimplement all the symfony2 constraints? What is the point of using a symfony validator at all then?